# Does Gson performance benefit from a resource pool in highly multi-threaded applications?

Tags: java, multithreading, gson, pool

I'm working on a highly multi-threaded Java application in which a single global Gson instance is shared between a large number of threads. At the moment I haven't noticed any performance deterioration however the volume of Json being processed has been relatively low up until now.

I was wondering if it would make sense to create a resource pool of Gson instances which every thread acquires and releases Gson instances from/to? To be specific, would it avoid scenarios where a thread is blocked waiting for access to the global Gson instance?

the Gson documentation mentions: "*Gson instances are Thread-safe so you can reuse them freely across multiple threads.*". However I'm having trouble figuring out whether this means it simply locks until it is done or if it uses some internal resource pool.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? I think GSON could be entirely sequential!

Comment: Instead of creating your own resource pool, you can use ThreadLocal if contention is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it would make sense to create a resource pool of Gson instances which every thread acquires and releases Gson instances from/to?

No, it wouldn't.
Gson thread-safety is accomplished by its immutability and creator/factory-like design.
You cannot change a `Gson` instance once its created, and the `Gson` class does not provide any way of doing so:

- It's immutable and its state cannot be changed from outside (it does not provide methods that can change its state + its fields are declared `final` to express this intent).
- It also does not allow to change its state transitively (say, it does not let you get a private field via a "get" method and change the object from outside).

Since there is nothing to modify in a `Gson` instance, it does not need synchronization mechanisms for read-only semantics:

- You don't need to pay for what you won't typically use (`synchronized` has its cost).
- It keeps its design and implementation simple.

Therefore invoking any `Gson` method is thread-safe, but the objects returned from these methods may lack thread-safety (for example, `JsonReader`/`JsonWriter` are not thread-safe; `JsonElement` and its subclasses may be thread-unsafe; etc).
Having this in mind you must be sure that your type adapters (Gson serializers/deserializers) are thread-safe by their design and do not change their internal state -- Gson relies on this heavily (as far as I know, all Gson built-in type adapters are immutable).
Obviously, if a particular type adapter uses synchronization mechanisms (and it's clearly a bottleneck), `Gson` `from` and `to` methods may await if they use such a type adapter, but you'd still be able to use `Gson` instance from other threads (however I would never design, implement and use type adapters that use synchronization under the hood).

So,

> a single global Gson instance is shared between a large number of threads

is totally fine.